# Modifying the look of @FileUpload.GetHtml helper

Tags: html, razor, multifile-uploader

I got a @Fileupload helper working pretty well. I just want to change the basic look like increasing the space between the lines or adding an hr between the last input file and input submit.

Is there a way by adding lines to this?

```
@if (!IsPost) {
    @FileUpload.GetHtml(
        initialNumberOfFiles:4,
        allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:false,
        includeFormTag:true,
        uploadText:"Send")
    }
```

As you see, the helper can send 4 files, but the look is too much packed.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What have you tried? You could probably achieve most of what you're asking via CSS.

Comment: Maybe =) can you explain how you would do it? If I change my P style it changes all the page. How can I say change or add a p line to this particular part? I'm a beginner

Comment: Wrap it in another element that you can target to prevent your styles from affecting the entire page. With more specific selectors, you can override existing styles: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Or, if the generated HTML already has a unique class, id, or attribute on the root element of that block of HTML that you can target, use that as the base of your selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend using this helper at all because these days, most browsers support `<input type="file" multiple/>` which is a lot more user-friendly than the FileUpload helper's multiple inputs. However, if you are wedded to the idea, you can do this to increase the space between the inputs:

```
<style>
    input[type=file]{
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
</style>
```